# PHP preg_match match consecutive newline chars

Tags: php, regex, newline

I am trying to prevent certain kinds of posts on my site, which are mostly meant to make it look like they contain some content but are just spam. Specifically, the posts are a few random words, some newline characters, and a random character.

So, I know some legit users might have use for using two newline chars (to create a blank line between paragraphs), but I figure 3+ can be marked as spam.

I tested this regex on regex101 and it works fine, but is never triggered when I test on my site, any ideas as to why? When I uncomment the echo line, it will show me the number 4 for my test data, so I know it sees the newlines.. is my regex formed incorrectly?!

Test data:

```
This is a potential


spam post
```

Code:

```
//echo substr_count($lowercaseBody, "\n");
if (preg_match('/\n{3,}./',  $lowercaseBody)){
    error("Stop Spamming my chan you .");
}
```

Comment: try :- `[\n\r]{3}`

Comment: Your test data seems to have only two new lines: [`(\n{2})`](https://regex101.com/r/sB6pE0/1)

Comment: @AKS that's problem of SO..making multiple newlines into single..go to edit question

Comment: @AKS, that must have been a mistake during the post, I have checked thing by hand about 300 times

Comment: That's interesting to know!

Comment: @rock321987, your answer solved the problem

Comment: @DanSmith No the answer by @rock321987 is not correct. It does not match 3 CRLF new-lines, it matches 3 consecutive `\r` or `\n` characters. What's already satisfied by two CRLF new lines (`\r\n\r\n`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data likely contains `CRLF`'s, not just `LF`'s.

The `substr_count` test does not care about the interleaving `CR`'s, but your regex patterns does.

Use `(\r?\n)` instead of the `\n` to allow both `CRLF`'s and `LF`'s (different browsers/OS's, may use different new-lines):

```
if (preg_match('/(\r?\n){3,}./',  $lowercaseBody)){
    error("Stop Spamming my chan you .");
}
```

Comment: One of the commentors above offered something similar, but this WAS the correct solution.  Can you tell me, what is the ? in the regex?

Comment: Also, can you tell me how to determine these characters in the future? I mean an echo doesn't show these. I suppose I could always loop over the data, but is there something easier?

Comment: It means the `\r` (`CR`) is optional. So that it matches both `\r\n` (`CRLF`) or plain `\n` (`LF`).